# Question about complex polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis

Hello everybody currently I have the following complex analysis question.

Suppose that $P(z)=a_0+a_1z+\dots+a_n z^n$ is a complex valued polynomial of degree at least $1$ and consider the punctured disk $D(0,\epsilon)\setminus \{p_1\}$ where $p_1 \in D(0,\epsilon)$.

**Claim**: There exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $P \colon D(0,\epsilon) \setminus 
\{p_1\} \to P(D(0,\epsilon))$ is surjective or in other words for large enough radius an arbitrary point $p_1 \in D(0,\epsilon)$ is negligible in the sense that for large enough radius the point $p_1$ because critical in the sense that $P$ fails to be injective on the image of $p_1$.

**Proof**: Suppose this is not the case then for any $\epsilon > 0$ the polynomial $P$ omits at least one value $w_1 \in \mathbb C$ and one has
$$
P\left(\mathbb C \setminus \{p_1\} \right) = \mathbb C \setminus \{w_1\},
$$
but since the polynomial $P$ is bounded around any ball $B(p_1,\delta)$ we can extend $P$ holomorphically to whole complex plane. But then it seems that the extension itself should be a polynomial via the cauchy integral theorem and hence by the fundamental theorem of algebra the above is impossible, hence we have a contradiction.

**Question**: Is the idea correct? I have some doubts about it since every rational function $R$ from the Riemann sphere to the Riemann sphere has degree $2d-2$ where $d$ denotes the degree. So if $\{p_1\}$ is not a critical point for the whole sphere then no matter how big the radius $\epsilon$ is chosen there is no other point $w \in \hat{\mathbb C}$ such that $P(w) = P(p_1)$.

Comment: What if $P(z) = (z-p_1)^n$?

Comment: Also one can have something like $P=z^n/4+1/1000$ and this one will contract most discs so won't be surjective from a disc to itself anyway